# Можно ли скрыть div в на моб. устройствах?

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте. 
Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 pc"></div>
```

Вопрос: можно ли в bootstrap сделать так чтобы на моб (col-xs) не присутствовал блок `pc` ? (по типу hidden-xs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абстрагируясь от bootstrap. Могу сказать что да.

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .pc {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Небольшое дополнение, я не знаю какие брейкпоинты у bootstrap, но в мире принято что до 425px телефоны, a от 768px до 1024px планшеты. Соответственно вы сами можете указать максимальный размер экрана при котором блок выводиться не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1" align="center">
            Col1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2" align="center">
            Col2
        </div>
        <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-5" align="center">
            Col3
        </div>
        <div class="visible-md col-md-3 " align="center">
            Col4
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-1" align="center">
            Col5
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```